# Symmetric Symplectic matrix preseve Lagrangian space

Tags: symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

Suppose $\psi$ a symmetric symplectic matrix(identify to symplectic map in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$), and $V$ a Lagrangian subspace in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Do we have
$\psi(V)=V$?

I'm trying to prove the product property of maslov index for Lagrangian space(base on the definition in the Introduction to Symplectic Topology by Mcduff and Salamon). In explicitly:

$\mu(\psi(t) V(t))=2\mu(\psi(t))+\mu(V(t))$

Here $\psi(t)$ a loop of symplectic map, $V(t)$ a loop in Lagrangian subspace, $\mu(X)$ means maslov index of $X$.

Now I reduce this problem into the linear algebra problem.But I have no idea to prove it.

Any reference about this property is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can add the condition that $\psi$ is positive definite if necessary, but I think it won't help.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this was true. I suggest looking for a counterexample involving a $4 \times 4$ matrix.